# Multiplying Bigintegers in parallel mode

Tags: java, android, biginteger

I want to write an android code which multiplies 10,000 numbers in parallel mode.
For example divide them into groups and multiply each group in thread..((async task)) and then multiply the results of each group.
But I dont know how to do it, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parallel stream.

```
List<BigInteger> integers = new ArrayList<>();
// fill data
BigInteger result = integers.parallelStream()
    .reduce(BigInteger.ONE, (a, e) -> a.multiply(e));
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A thread pool can run multiple parallel instances of a task, so you should ensure that your code is thread-safe. Enclose variables that can be accessed by more than one thread in a synchronized block. This approach will prevent one thread from reading the variable while another is writing to it. Typically, this situation arises with static variables, but it also occurs in any object that is only instantiated once.

By using Thread Pool Concept you can use the given link for code:

https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html#ClassStructure

While using **async task** you can check this also:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/developing-android-applications-using-parallel-programming